# jquery on keypress missing characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

When trying to listen for keypress and then submit data for validation, the value appears to be 1 character behind...

```
$(function () {
    $('.entry').on('change keypress', function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>
        <input class='entry' type='text' id='name' name='name'>
    </td>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ba6688my/)

Comment: Try `keydown` event instead of `keypress`

Comment: no change on keydown vs. keypress

Answer (score 5):

Try using `input` event

```
$(".entry").on("input", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ba6688my/1/

Comment: You seriously should not use `alert` in Demo, especially this one with `input` event, that'll block the user and will not be able to use it, Here's better [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ba6688my/2/), feel free to add in answer if you think this will improve answer :)

Comment: @Tushar Used `js` from Question for demonstration purposes only ; appear that OP actually use `alert` for the same ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `input` event instead:

```
$(function(){
    $('.entry').on('input',function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```